# Tarea de tema de arrays en el que nos piden hacer arte ascii java

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy cursando 1DAW y estamos con el tema de los array, el cual nos piden hacer un programa con datos que nos dan. Estoy atascado... adjunto el enunciado y lo que yo llevo de programa. Un saludo y muchas gracias

Hola compañeros. Nuestros profes se están poniendo originales este año. Nos han mandado una actividad en el tema de array's en el que nos piden hacer arte ascii. Os pongo el enunciado a ver si tenéis alguna idea. Por supuesto muchas gracias por vuestras molestias.

se ha declarado un array bidimensional de String donde la primera dimensión tendrá siete elementos (cada una de las "capas" o "pisos" de los siete caracteres de altura que va a tener cada cifra).
cada uno de esos elementos será a su vez un array unidimensional de String de diez elementos. Cada uno de esos diez elementos es una parte del patrón de las cifras del 0 al 9 (la "capa" o "piso" del dígito que corresponde a cada nivel).
El array tendrá el siguiente contenido:

imagen en la foto

Este array lo puedes copiar y pegar a tu código como variable auxiliar que contiene los modelos ASCII de las cifras. En esta estructura tendremos toda la información necesaria para poder representar "en grande" o tamaño "gigante" cada carácter numérico del 0 al 9. Se trata, por tanto, de que escribas un programa en Java que, dada una entrada numérica por teclado, genere una cadena de caracteres que lo represente de manera "gigante". Por ejemplo, si se introdujera por teclado el número 51628, se generaría una cadena que al imprimirla por pantalla tendría el siguiente aspecto:

imagen en la foto

Y así con cualquier otro texto formado únicamente por cifras que se introdujera desde teclado.

Para ello tendrás que escribir un programa en Java que:

Declare un array bidimensional de objetos String que contenga los modelos ASCII de las cifras numéricas en tamaño "gigante". Se trata del array anterior (String[][] plantillaNumeros), que simplemente tendrás que insertar en tu código (por ejemplo, en la sección de variables auxiliares).
Solicite un número entero no negativo de como máximo diez cifras. Se deben admitir ceros a la izquierda. Si no se introduce un valor válido, se volverá a pedir hasta que lo sea. Utilizar como entrada una cadena de caracteres (no un valor entero) y usar como filtro de comprobación una expresión regular.
Genere la cadena final (de siete líneas) que contendrá la representación "gigante" del número.

Muestre por pantalla esa cadena.

Las imágenes no las puedo poner en el mensaje. Adjunto foto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi código de momento es:

```
public class Ejercicio03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //----------------------------------------------
        //          Declaración de variables 
        //----------------------------------------------
        // Variables de entrada

        long double numero= 0;
        
        // Variables de salida

        
        // Variables auxiliares
        // 1. Declaramos el array con los modelos ASCII de las cifras
        
        String[][] plantillaNumeros ={{"   ###   ","    #    ","  #####  ","  #####  "," #       "," ####### ","  #####  "," ####### ","  #####  ","  #####  "},
                                  {"  #   #  ","   ##    "," #     # "," #     # "," #    #  "," #       "," #     # "," #    #  "," #     # "," #     # "},
                                  {" #     # ","  # #    ","       # ","       # "," #    #  "," #       "," #       ","     #   "," #     # "," #     # "},
                                  {" #     # ","    #    ","  #####  ","  #####  "," #    #  "," ######  "," ######  ","    #    ","  #####  ","  ###### "},
                                  {" #     # ","    #    "," #       ","       # "," ####### ","       # "," #     # ","   #     "," #     # ","       # "},
                                  {"  #   #  ","    #    "," #       "," #     # ","      #  "," #     # "," #     # ","   #     "," #     # "," #     # "},
                                  {"   ###   ","  #####  "," ####### ","  #####  ","      #  ","  #####  ","  #####  ","   #     ","  #####  ","  #####  "}};
 
        int[] stack = new int[10];
        int i=0;

        
        
        
        // Clase Scanner para petición de datos de entrada
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        

        //----------------------------------------------
        //                Entrada de datos 
        //----------------------------------------------
        System.out.println("CIFRAS GIGANTES");
        System.out.println("---------------");
        // 2. Solicitamos un número entero no negativo de como máximo diez cifras
        
        System.out.println("Introduce el numero que quieres mostrar");
    
        numero=teclado.nextInt();
        
        while (numero < 0 || año > 9999999999) {
    
            try {
            System.out.print("Introduzca año (1900-2100): ");
            año = Integer.parseInt(teclado.nextLine());
            if (año < 1900 || año > 2100)
            System.out.println("Error de lectura: valor ha de ser entre 1900 y 2100");}
        
            catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error de lectura: no es un número entero valido.");}
        }
        
        
        if(numero==0){
 
        for(int j=0;j<7;j++){
                System.out.println(plantillaNumeros[j][0]); }
         }
        
        else {
            while(numero > 0){
 
            stack[i]= numero % 10;
            numero = numero / 10;
            i++;}
            
        int [] stack2 = new int[i];
        
        for (int j=0;j<stack2.length;j++){
            stack2[j] = stack[j];}

        
        
        
        //----------------------------------------------
        //                 Procesamiento 
        //----------------------------------------------
        // 3. Generamos el resultado final
        
        // 3.1. Declaramos un array de cadenas para almacenar temporalmente cada nivel del texto final

        
        
        
        // 3.2. Recorremos cada nivel del array de patrones

        
        
        
        
        
        // 3.3. Una vez rellenados todos los niveles del array temporal, recorremos ese array 

            // 3.3.1. Vamos concatenando en una única variable final todos los niveles, separándolos por medio de un avance de línea ('\n')

            
        //----------------------------------------------
        //              Salida de resultados 
        //----------------------------------------------
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("RESULTADO");
        System.out.println("---------");
        // 4. Mostramos por pantalla un único String que contiene el número "gigante"
        
        for(int j=0;j<7;j++){
            for(int k=stack2.length-1;k>-1;k--){
                System.out.print(plantillaNumeros[j][stack2[k]]);
            }
           System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: Opción más fácil :  creas una variable por cada número y guardas allí la matriz que representa ese número como "arte ascii". Opción un poco más bonita: un array que, por cada posición del 0 al 9, guarde la matriz. Así, en cualquiera de los casos recibes el número en el Scanner y buscas el arte que corresponde. Al final, vas pintando cada número en la salida y ya está :)

Answer (score 0):

la solución es extremadamente sencilla, para llegar a ella, debes pensar "al reves", elijo un número (32) y lo escribo (literalmente) como me pide el profe, luego escribo un código, que haga lo que acabo de hacer.
Y que acabo de hacer?... primero escribí el "techo" del "3" seguido por el techo del "2", apliqué un salto de linea, luego el "segundo piso" del 3 y del 2, así hasta llegar a la base, esto traducido a código sería así:

```
void imprimeGigantes( int numeros[] ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < 7; i++ ) {
        for( int h = 0; h < numeros.length; h++ ) {
            int numero = numeros[ h ];
            System.out.print( plantillaNumeros[ i ][ numero ] );
        }
        System.out.println( "" );
    }
}
```

Que hace este método:

El for externo, recorre los "pisos" de "plantillaNumeros" (7), el interno recorre el array con los números a imprimir, dentro de este for, declaro la variable "numero" y le asigno el valor correspondiente (le decimos al programa cual es el número del que debo imprimir el "piso"), solo resta imprimir la linea, y agregar después del for, el salto de linea.

Podemos ahorrarnos la declaración de la variable "numero" con:
System.out.print( plantillaNumeros[ i ][ numeros[ h ] ] );

Espero haberte ayudado.